# jQuery problems with each() and show()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have three divs on a webpage, and I want to call `show()` (jQuery UI) on each when they are in view. This is working, but for some reason they seem to **all** fade in, even if only the first one is visible. What I want is for them each to be checked individually, and get `show()` called on them individually. Here is my code:

```
$('.right-caption').each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
function isInView(elem){
   return $(elem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).height();
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.right-caption').each(function() {
        if (isInView($(this))) {
            $(this).show("drop", { direction: "right" }, 1200);
        }
    });
});
```

Am I using the each() function incorrectly? Or should I be using something else? The only other javascript I'm using is a bootstrap plugin.

Comment: Here's a codepen demonstrating: https://codepen.io/Awesomennjawarrior/pen/zwvrxe?editors=0010

Comment: Do you want each element to fade in on it's own. Example: 1, 2, and then 3. Or do you wish to have all 3 appear at once?

Comment: I want each to fade in on it's own, each as they scroll onto the screen (the first example you gave)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your script. The fundamental problem was that you cannot get the offset of a hidden element (pls check [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)). I also debounced to reduce the calls to the scroll handler. Now it executes around each 60 ms.

```
$(function() {
  var $divs = $('div'),
    $window = $(window),
    $windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    divsOfsets = [];

  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
        var timeout;

        return function debounced() {
            var obj = this,
                args = arguments;

            function delayed() {
                if (!execAsap)
                    func.apply(obj, args);
                timeout = null;
            }

            if (timeout)
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            else if (execAsap)
                func.apply(obj, args);

            timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
        };
    };
  var handleScroll = function () {
    var scrlt = $window.scrollTop(),
      len = divsOfsets.length;
    while (len--) {
      if ((scrlt + $windowHeight) > divsOfsets[len]) {
        $divs.eq(len).show(1200);
      }
    }
  };

  $divs.each(function() {
    divsOfsets.push($(this).offset().top);
  });
  $divs.hide();
  $window.scroll(debounce(handleScroll, 60));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest something like this:

```
$(function() {
  //hide them in the first place
  $('div').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });

  function isInView(elem) {
    return $(elem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).height();
  }
  //when the user scrolls, check, and if any of the divs are in sight, then show that div
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".left-caption").each(function(i, el) {
      if (isInView($(el))) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(el).show("drop", {
            direction: "left"
          }, 1000);
        }, 400 + i * 400);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Working Pen Forked: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmpZVL

**Update**

Using `.animate()` and proper classes, you can do this too.

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-caption off-screen">These Divs Should</div>
<div class="left-caption off-screen">Fadein/show</div>
<div class="left-caption off-screen">individually</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.off-screen {
  margin-left: -316px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  //when the user scrolls, check, and if any of the divs are in sight, then show that div
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".left-caption").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).hasClass("off-screen")) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(el).animate({
            marginLeft: "5px"
          }, 1000).removeClass("off-screen");
        }, 400 + i * 400);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple work-around. I ended up using this answer instead of the one above, although I think the answer above more fully gave what I had asked for. However, this is simple and still gives me the affect I wanted. :)

Comment: Except, just so everyone knows, as itacode said, my isInVeiw function will not work properly on the elements, since they are hidden. I ended up using a different way of checking if they were in view. :)

Comment: Then you could always adjust the margin to be negative and then use `.animate()` to return the margin to 0. Might update my answer if you think it would be helpful to have `offset`.